# Unable to search for "no" in chat rooms

Tags: support, chat, search

In [chat searches](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search), any search for the text "no" yields no results:

- ["No" said by me in the Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=no&user=230261&room=89) (no results although I have definitely said "no")
- [RSS Feed for "no" in general](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/search/no) (it's empty)

I thought perhaps it was because of a minimum search term length, but "ok" yields results:

- ["Ok" said by me in the Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=ok&user=230261&room=89)
- [RSS Feed for "ok" in general](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/search/ok)

It *seems* like it is perhaps on a list of excluded words, as I can search for, say, ["b"](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/search/b) but not ["a"](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/search/a), and it seems reasonable for "a" to be on an exclusion list. But this seems strange to me, why would "no" be excluded but not "yes" or "ok"?

My question is: Why is this? Is it a bug? Is it intentional and part of an exclusion list (in which case I wonder if it should be removed from that list, based on the acceptance of e.g. "yes")? If the latter, what are the other excluded words?

Comment: Perhaps it's an excluded word because there is never a need to search for that word on it's own. You'd need other keywords, which would be found on their own without needing "no" with them. Possibly the less they allow "trivial" words to be in searches the faster the query can be?

Comment: I wish there was a search that match everything, because that would give an RSS feed of all messages in the room.

Comment: They probably have an ad-hoc list of stopwords that are dropped from the search. I experimentally verified that one-letter searches work unless that letter is A.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words No and OK are commonly included in stop word lists.

Comment: Yeah, it sound like they remove these words. What about `the` and `I`?

Comment: @Tim ["I"](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/search/i) works, ["the"](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/search/the) does not.

Comment: @Won't They must have a strange exclusion list, "ok" works fine, as does "i", although not "a".

Comment: I guess it's filtered out, searches for ["no way"](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=no+way&user=230261&room=89) ignore the "no".